# how do I set up a grouping query on the server side. I want set up the query so I can use it for a pie chart in front end, using d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, jwt

I am using this query to count and group occupation types. I need to do this in order to create a pie chart for the client side for the front end. I don't think I need to input anything, I just want to get the information sorted and counted. User_Id is just referenced just in case I get any errors with authorization of the jwt token. The user_id is not referenced in the table that I am pulling information from, it's just there for authorization purposes.

```
router.get("/occupation/:user_id", authorization, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        console.log(req);
        const result = await pool.query(
            "SELECT occupation,COUNT(occupation) FROM resources GROUP BY occupation;",
            [req.params.user_id][req.body.occupation]

            // [req.body.json
            // ]
        );

        console.log(req.body);

        res.status(200).json({
            status: "success",
            data: {
                occupation: result.rows, //this gets the one row we need
            },
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
    }
});
```

Comment: How do you want it grouped? Also, you can use d3 utility functions on the back-end

Comment: Hi there I want to pull all of  the occupation types, count them and group them then I want to use the pie chart to display the amount out of a percentage. I know the query provides the name and values of what needs to be in the pie graph but I don't know how to make the query work in the get request.

Comment: Your sql query looks like it is already doing that

Comment: when I use postman to test the endpoint it doesn't complete the request

Comment: Sounds like you need to figure that out first!

Answer (score 0):

```
router.get("/occ", authorization, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        console.log(req);
        const result = await pool.query(
            // "SELECT occupation,COUNT(occupation) FROM resources GROUP BY occupation;",

            "SELECT occupation,COUNT(occupation) as values FROM resources GROUP BY occupation"
        );

        console.log(req);
        console.log(result);
        res.status(200).json({
            status: "success",
            data: {
                occupationResults: result.rows, //this gets the one row we need
            },
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
    }
});
```